# Grid-view is not formed in horizontal-scrolling-pages like home screen when app is in Background or Process is died

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am developing [Horizontal Scrolling pages](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/horizontal-scrolling-pages/) and [tabs](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

MY app is working well in all devices in foreground, but when it goes to background, after one hour, the logs saying that Process **com.example.myapp has died**. When i reopen the app , the gridview data is not appearing but when scrolling horizontally , getView() method displaying all data like images and text.

that means app has data but view is not formed when process has died. And if i press back button and re-open the app, It is working good

My MainActivity.java is here

```
package com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.phone;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;

import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.R;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.listener.phone.CustomViewPager;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.chat.phone.ChatFragmentTab;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.dialpad.phone.DialerFragment;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.home.phone.AlarmFragmentPhone;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.home.phone.HomeFragment;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.home.phone.HomeFragmentTab;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.home.phone.InfoFragPhone;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.home.phone.MapPhone;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.home.phone.WeatherFragmentPhone;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.messages.phone.MessagesFragment;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.settings.phone.AboutFragment;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.tablet.ConstantsManager;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.tablet.OnFragmentChangedListenerPhone;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.utils.common.UConnectUtils;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, OnFragmentChangedListenerPhone {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_phone);

        this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
        initialiseViewPager();
    }


    /**
     * Initialise ViewPager
     */
    private void initialiseViewPager() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,HomeFragmentTab.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, DialerFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,MessagesFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,ChatFragmentTab.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, AboutFragment.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        this.mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabviewpager);
        this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        this.mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentChangePhone(JSONObject response, String whichView, String title, String mPhoneNo) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            if(response != null)
                b.putString("JSONObject", response.toString());
            if(title != null)
                b.putString("Title", title);

            String propertyId = UConnectUtils.getPropertyId(mPref, getString(R.string.property_id));
            b.putString(UConnectUtils.PROPERTY_ID_KEY, propertyId);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment = null;

            if (whichView.equals(ConstantsManager.GRIDVIEWPAGER)) {
//              getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
            } else if (whichView.equals(ConstantsManager.WEATHER)) {
                fragment = new WeatherFragmentPhone();
            }else if (whichView.equals(ConstantsManager.ALARM)) {
                fragment = new AlarmFragmentPhone();
            }else if (whichView.equals(ConstantsManager.MAPS)) {
                fragment = new MapPhone();
            }else if (whichView.equals(ConstantsManager.HELP)) {
            fragment = new InfoFragPhone();
            }

            if (whichView.equals(ConstantsManager.MAPS)) { // to show plus-icon on map top right corner
                HomeFragment.getInstance().onGridViewVisibilityChanged(true);
                HomeFragmentTab.getInstance().onFragmentTabChange(View.VISIBLE , title, "", View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (!whichView.equals(ConstantsManager.GRIDVIEWPAGER)) {
                HomeFragment.getInstance().onGridViewVisibilityChanged(true);
                HomeFragmentTab.getInstance().onFragmentTabChange(View.VISIBLE , title, mPhoneNo, View.GONE);
            } 

            fragment.setArguments(b);
            ft.add(R.id.main_home_frag, fragment);
            if (whichView.equals(ConstantsManager.GRIDVIEWPAGER)) {
                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            } else {
                ft.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
            }
            ft.commit();

        }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

and my HomeFragmentTab.java is

```
package com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.home.phone;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.R;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.phone.MainActivity;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.tablet.ConstantsManager;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.tablet.OnFragmentTabChangedListener;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class HomeFragmentTab extends Fragment implements OnFragmentTabChangedListener{
    private static final String TAG = HomeFragmentTab.class.getSimpleName();
    private static HomeFragmentTab tab;
    private MainActivity activityPhone;

    public static HomeFragmentTab getInstance() {
        return tab;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        activityPhone = (MainActivity) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v;
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView");


        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hometab_phone, container, false);

        tab = this;

        activityPhone.onFragmentChangePhone(null, ConstantsManager.GRIDVIEWPAGER, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "");


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentTabChange(int i, String title, String mPhoneNo, int mapV) {

    }

}
```

and HomeFragment.java is

```
package com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.home.phone;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.R;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.ImageCacheManager;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.cms.tablet.TestTopics;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.cms.tablet.TopicList;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.phone.MainActivity;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.ui.tablet.onGridViewVisibilityChangedListener;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.utils.common.UCConstants;
import com.bbgusa.bbgdemo.utils.common.UConnectUtils;
import com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator;
import com.viewpagerindicator.IconPagerAdapter;
import com.viewpagerindicator.PageIndicator;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements onGridViewVisibilityChangedListener{

    private static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private MainActivity activity;
    private PageIndicator mIndicator;
    private Animation mRotateAnim;
    private Dialog indiacatorDialog;
    private LinearLayout homeFragmentLL;
    private static HomeFragment homeFragment;

    public static final HomeFragment getInstance() {
        return homeFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = (MainActivity) activity;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_phone, container, false);
        homeFragment = this;

        UConnectUtils.setLauncher(true);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mIndicator = (IconPageIndicator) v.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        homeFragmentLL = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.homeFragment);

        indiacatorDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        indiacatorDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        indiacatorDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        indiacatorDialog.setContentView(R.layout.indicator_dialog);
        indiacatorDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        Window window = indiacatorDialog.getWindow();
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        mRotateAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate_and_scale);
        UConnectUtils.addAnimationFrameCount(mRotateAnim);
        indicatorAnim();


         // for property id
//      if (activity.isInterNetAvailable()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView========== isInterNetAvailable");
        new CmsPropertyAsync(activity).execute(UCConstants.CMS_CONFIG_URL, UCConstants.CMS_CONFIG_KEY);
//      }
        return v;
    }

    protected void parseJson(JSONObject rootResponce) {
        TestTopics.imageUrls.clear();
        TestTopics.titles.clear();
        TestTopics.mMainMenuID.clear();
        TestTopics.mViewType.clear();
        TestTopics.mPhoneNo.clear();
        try {
            //get the Version
            String version = rootResponce.optString("VERSION");

            SharedPreferences mPref;
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit;

            mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            edit = mPref.edit();
            edit.putString(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_cms_version_key), version).commit();

            JSONArray jsonArray = rootResponce.getJSONArray("MAINMENU");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject childMenuObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int mainMenuID = childMenuObject.optInt("mainMenuId");
                String title = childMenuObject.optString("title");
                String viewType = childMenuObject.optString("viewType");
                String imageUrl = childMenuObject.optString("imageUrl");
                String phoneNo = childMenuObject.optString("phoneNo");

                TestTopics.mMainMenuID.add(mainMenuID);
                TestTopics.imageUrls.add(imageUrl);
                TestTopics.titles.add(title);
                TestTopics.mViewType.add(viewType);
                TestTopics.mPhoneNo.add(phoneNo);
            }

            // Create a TopicList for this demo. Save it as the shared instance
            // in
            // TopicList
            String sampleText = getResources().getString(R.string.sample_topic_text);
            TopicList tlist = new TopicList(sampleText);
            TopicList.setInstance(tlist);

            // Create an adapter object that creates the fragments that we need
            // to display the images and titles of all the topics.

            MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tlist, getResources());
//          mViewPager.removeAllViews();
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            //  mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
            mIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
            mIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);
            mIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();

            ViewTreeObserver observer = mViewPager.getViewTreeObserver();
            observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                   mViewPager.bringChildToFront(mViewPager.getChildAt(0));

                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= UCConstants.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1){
                        mViewPager.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }else{
                        mViewPager.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });

            /*Fragment f = new GridViewFragment();
            FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            t.replace(R.id.main_home_frag, f);
            t.commit();*/

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adapter class
     * 
     * This adapter class sets up GridFragment objects to be displayed by a
     * ViewPager.
     */

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {

        private TopicList mTopicList;
        private int mNumItems = 0;
        private int mNumFragments = 0;

        /**
         * Return a new adapter.
         */

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, TopicList db, Resources res) {
            super(fm);
            setup(db, res);
        }

        /**
         * Get the number of fragments to be displayed in the ViewPager.
         */

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.i(TAG, "getCount : mNumFragments = "+mNumFragments);
            return mNumFragments;
        }

        /**
         * Return a new GridFragment that is used to display n items at the
         * position given.
         * 
         * @param position
         *            int - the position of the fragement; 0..numFragments-1
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // Create a new Fragment and supply the fragment number, image
            // position, and image count as arguments.
            // (This was how arguments were handled in the original pager
            // example.)
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("num", position + 1);
            args.putInt("firstImage", position * mNumItems);

            // The last page might not have the full number of items.
            int imageCount = mNumItems;
            if (position == (mNumFragments - 1)) {
                int numTopics = mTopicList.getNumTopics();
                int rem = numTopics % mNumItems;
                if (rem > 0)
                    imageCount = rem;
            }
            args.putInt("imageCount", imageCount);
            args.putSerializable("topicList", TopicList.getInstance());

            // Return a new GridFragment object.
            Log.i(TAG, "created fragmenat number:==== "+position+" "+1);
            GridViewFragmentPhone f = new GridViewFragmentPhone();
            f.setArguments(args);
            Log.i(TAG, "getItem : imageCount = "+imageCount);

            return f;
        }

        /**
         * Set up the adapter using information from a TopicList and resources
         * object. When this method completes, all the instance variables of the
         * adapter are valid;
         * 
         * @param tlist
         *            TopicList
         * @param res
         *            Resources
         * @return void
         */

        void setup(TopicList tlist, Resources res) {
            mTopicList = tlist;

            if ((tlist == null) || (res == null)) {
                mNumItems = 2;//DEFAULT_NUM_ITEMS;
                mNumFragments = 2;//DEFAULT_NUM_FRAGMENTS;
            } else {
                int numTopics = tlist.getNumTopics();
                int numRowsGV = res.getInteger(R.integer.num_of_rows_gridview);
                int numColsGV = res.getInteger(R.integer.num_of_cols_gridview);
                int numTopicsPerPage = numRowsGV * numColsGV;
                int numFragments = numTopics / numTopicsPerPage;
                if (numTopics % numTopicsPerPage != 0)
                    numFragments++; // Add one if there is a partial page

                mNumFragments = numFragments;
                mNumItems = numTopicsPerPage;
            }
        } // end setup

        @Override
        public int getIconResId(int index) {
             int[] ICON = new int[mNumFragments];

            for (int i = 0; i < mNumFragments; i++) {
                ICON[i] = R.drawable.slidericon;
            }
             return ICON[index % ICON.length];
        }
    } // end class MyAdapter


    @Override
    public void onGridViewVisibilityChanged(boolean hide) {
        if(hide){
            homeFragmentLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            homeFragmentLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        activity = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class CmsPropertyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        MainActivity context;

        CmsPropertyAsync(MainActivity activityTab) {
            context = activityTab;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String propertyId = UConnectUtils.getPropertyId(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context),getResources().getString(R.string.property_id));
            if(propertyId != null && propertyId.length() > 0){
                return propertyId;
            }
            return UConnectUtils.requestPropertyId(params[0], params[1]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String propertyId) {
            if(propertyId == null){
                indiacatorDialog.dismiss();
                showPropertyIdTimeoutAlert(getActivity());
                return;
            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
            editor.putString(getString(R.string.property_id),propertyId).commit();

            String url = null;
            String locale = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
            url = UCConstants.CMS_BASE_URL+"mainMenu?propertyId="+propertyId+"&lang="+locale;
            JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    parseJson(response);
                    indiacatorDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (activity != null) {
//                      activity.getConnection(error);
                    }
                    indiacatorDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            ImageCacheManager.getInstance().getQueueForMainmenu().add(jsObjRequest);
        }
    }

    private void indicatorAnim() {
        if (indiacatorDialog != null) {
            ImageView alertIndicator = (ImageView) indiacatorDialog.findViewById(R.id.alert_indicator);
            alertIndicator.startAnimation(mRotateAnim);
            if (!getActivity().isFinishing()) {
                indiacatorDialog.show();
            }
        }
    }

    //  Show alert for Time out
     private void showPropertyIdTimeoutAlert(final Activity context) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon);
        alertDialog.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.timeout_msg));
        alertDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.timeout_msg2));
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        indicatorAnim();
                        //  for property id
                        new CmsPropertyAsync(activity).execute(UCConstants.CMS_CONFIG_URL, UCConstants.CMS_CONFIG_KEY);
                    }
            });

         alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
         });
         AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
         alert.setCancelable(false);
         alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
         if (context != null && !context.isFinishing()) {
             alert.show();
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, some data is being saved with onSavedInstaceState(). The data is not being deleted when process has been killed on LowMemory.

I fixed this with

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Just do not call super class. Just comment like above